# How can I turn my pasta salad into a pickle?

Tags: pasta, food-preservation, pickling

A pickle that would preserve it for a week?

Would it ruin the taste of the pasta salad?

Comment: Are you asking about [pickling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickling) and [salt-curing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt-cured_meat) (e.g. [salt pork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_pork))? Or just adding small quantities to various things?

Comment: Small quantities to various things (or as much as is needed to preserve it) - I'm not sure if I want to turn my lunch into a pasta pickle.

Comment: Wow, how far ahead of time are you making your lunch? In any case, if what you're really trying to do is preserve a particular dish (pasta with... what?) for longer (how long?) you might want to ask your question more directly - what things would help it last longer, and how much longer?

Comment: This question needs a lot more specifics.  Why are you trying to preserve pasta?  Raw or cooked?  For how long?  With what?  As it stands, it's a pretty meaninless question: dried pasta lasts forever.

Comment: Cooked pasta, for at least a week, with vinegar

Comment: If you want to preserve it for a week with acid, you have to pickle it. There is no way around it.

Comment: Okay, I'll change the question title then.

Comment: Cooked pasta can last a week in a cold fridge anyway, right? I'm pretty sure I've eaten leftovers that old...

Comment: Why would you pickle pasta anyways? If you really need to preserve it for a long time just freeze it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use pickling when you want something to last months not days.

In regards to your second question: it certainly wouldn't be pasta salad any more.

If you want to experiment with pasta pickle then sure it sounds like a good idea, if you want to preserve pasta for a week split it into several air tight containers and stick it in the fridge.